# Explain the following C++ code part

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
//class start--

//Global variable

static PMSK *savepr;
static PRC *prs;

//inside some method

static PMSK wkpm;
PMSK *pm;

if (ipf) {
    k = to_bits(312, &msk);     // This will return k=24 and msk =char(00000001),  
    if ( pm->orbits[k] & msk )  // See the answer of my previous question.
        prs[i].pccused = 1; 
}
```

For the to_bits method pls see the link

[Explain the following C++ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562502/explain-the-following-c-method)

I am not familiar with C++ coding. What is goin on in the second if block? And explain the variable declarations also?

Thanks

Comment: This does not compile. EDIT: ah, sorry, you wondered about the variable declarations yourself. Yes, they seem to be missing. Where did you find the code?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to know about the `if`-clause:

`if ( pm->orbits[k] & msk )` contains the [bitwise-AND operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), which takes the bits of `pm->orbits[k]` and the bits of `msk` and returns those bits that were in both values (that's the "AND" part).

For example:
0010 1101 & 1010 1010 = 0010 1000

**EDIT:**
I suggest you read [a good beginners C++ book](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/) to learn about [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29#C_and_C.2B.2B) (the `->`) and arrays (the `[k]`).

Since you gave no information regarding the PMSK type I have no idea what `mp->orbits[k]` will give you, apart from this: the PMSK struct or class seems to contain an array called orbits, and `pm->orbits[24]` denotes its 25th (not the 24th!) element.

Comment: pm->orbits[k] What will this return if the value of K is 24?

Comment: Also what is the meaning of -> operator. Also pm is a type of PMSK , so what does that mean. The rest of the part you explained clearly.

Comment: So inside the if clause it will return true or false ?

Comment: @JavaBits: -> is used for a pointer. It is similar to a '.' but only that it is used for pointers instead of normal variables. pm->orbits[k] means that there is an array named 'orbits' in pm variable. And this is accessing its kth element.

Comment: So we can say if PMSK is class and pm is a object which contains an array orbits[]. Am I correct? Thanks for ur suggestions.

Comment: PMSK seems to be a class or struct (these two are more or less the same in C++) which contains an array called orbits, yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( pm->orbits[k] & msk ) // check to see if they aare bit-by-bit identical.
```

And how the variable declarations are goin on?  no idea what you mean, clarify.

Comment: What i meant was What is the meaning of "static PRC *prs; " ? Similarly for other variable declarations.

Comment: So will it return true or false?

Comment: Also in the variable declaration when we are saying static PMSK *savepr; then is PMSK a class and save pr is an object - like in JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

```
class start--
```

This is invalid syntax.

```
static PMSK *savepr;
static PRC *prs;
```

These are pointers to objects of type PMSK, PRC with internal linkage.

```
static PMSK wkpm;
PMSK *pm;
```

An instance of object PMSK with internal linkage and a pointer to a PMSK object "wkpm" with translation-unit scope.

```
    if(ipf){
        k = to_bits(312, &msk);  // you might want to post this "to_bits" function

    if ( pm->orbits[k] & msk )  // this returns the k+1 object in the array "orbits" and performs a bitwise AND with "msk"
// you might want to post the declaration for this pm instance and the class decaration
        prs[i].pccused = 1;  // this sets the member variable "pcussed" of object i + 1 in the array "prs" to 1
}
```

Comment: This is the link for the to_bits method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562502/explain-the-following-c-method

Comment: so if we are using PMSK *pm what does that mean in C++?