# Conversion from C++ to Java(Returning more than one value in java)

Tags: java, c++, bitset

```
Not getting the char value: 
#define XL 33 
#define OR 113 
#define NOR 313 
#define TN 344 

int to_bits(int critn,char *mask) 
{ 
unsigned int x; 
int begin; 

if (critn < XL) begin = 1; 
else if (critn < OR) begin = XL; 
else if (critn < NOR) begin = OR; 
else if (critn <= TN) begin = NOR; 
else begin = 0; 
x = critn - begin; 

*mask = (char)(0x80 >> (x % 8)); 

return (int)(x >> 3); // fast divide by 8 
}
```

For explanations and example of the method please see
[Explain the following C++ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562502/explain-the-following-c-method).

I have written the following method in Java:

```
ClassA{

final static int xl = 33;
final static int or = 113;
final static int nor = 313;
final static int tn = 344;

public int to_bits(int critn){
    int x;
    int begin;

    if(critn<xl)
     begin = 1;
    else if (critn<or) 
     begin = xl;
    else if (critn<nor)
     begin = or;
    else if (critn<tn) 
     begin = nor;
    else begin = 0;

     x = critn - begin;

    char mask = (char)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
    System.out.println(mask);

    return (int)(x >> 3);

}


public static void main(String args[]){
    ClassA a =new ClassA();
    a.to_bits(312);

}

}
```

Can we take the output of mask into Bitset object.
I am getting out put as (a special char output for the char field)

24.

Please suggest also how to get both the character and integer values. thanks

Comment: @JavaBits: this is a better question, thanks.

Comment: Is your question really "How can I return more than one item from a function?".

Comment: Is your question, "How do I change this so that to_bits returns a [BitSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)?

Comment: You claim that by printlning a char, you get the output 24?

Comment: No im returning a int - that is giving 24 output. the char which is printed inside the method is printed as a small box symbol(a special character)

Comment: @razlebe : No my question is how can get the char value? @Oli Charlesworth: yes that would be more helpful cause in java we dont have a pointer concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking if you can output the mask as binary?

If so, this will do the job:

```
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(mask));
```

or in hexadecimal:

```
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(mask));
```

(**EDIT** - I previously said to use `Integer.toString(mask, 2 /* or 16 */)`, but that formats the number as signed ... which is obviously confusing you.)

---

You will eventually also want to know to return more than one value from a java method call.  The answer is to return the values in an array (or object); e.g.

```
    return new int[]{(char)(0x80 >> (x % 8)), x >> 3});
```

or set them in a mutable array or object passed as a parameter.

---

I have a feeling that you have not realized that `char` is a 16 bit type in Java.  If you want a type that is equivalent to a C / C++ `char`, the closest is the Java `byte` type - a signed 8 bit type.

---

On further reflection, the simplest approach is to do the calculations to give you `int` values; e.g.

```
    return new int[]{0x80 >> (x % 8), x >> 3});
```

and have the caller cast either value to some other type *if required*.

Assuming that these values are intended to be used for bitwise operation, the fact that they might *look* negative is irrelevant ... provided that the bit patterns are correct.  Remember that they are bit patterns and not numbers.  If that is confusing, use `Integer.toHexString(...)` or `Integer.toBinaryString(...)` to print them out in unsigned form.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Yes but as it is of type signed its returning negative sign(-) before the value.

Comment: If it is really a bit mask, the fact that there is a negative sign is irrelevant.  You are not using it as a number: you are using it as a bit pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful if not considering the sign. Else we can stick to the char.

//char mask = (char)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
byte mask = (byte)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
System.out.println(Integer.toString(mask,2));

output: 1  24

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: There is no way to return more than one value.

The long answer is: You can put more than one value into one value. 
If you want to return only a few values and all your values are of the same type, use an array. (see Stephen C's answer)
Otherwise use an Object. For your case:

```
class MaskAndBits {
      char mask;
      int bits;
      public BitsAndMask(char mask, int bits) {
        this.mask = mask;
        this.bits = bits;
      }
 }
```

and then `return new Whatever((char)(0x80 >> (x % 8));, (int)(x >> 3))`.
Overall this is a lot more to type than the array solution, but its harder to 
mix up the two values returned ;-)